# jQuery UI Menu border color

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have implemented the jQuery UI Menu on this page: http://dormfair.com/about.php

As you can see, the border color everywhere on the website is light blue (#B7DDF2)
BUT the border color in the jQuery UI menu is grey. I've been trying to change that grey to color to #B7DDF2 for a long time to no avail. I've searched the web and StackOverflow as well.

Hope someone can help!

```
.ui-menu { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.ui-menu > li { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto !important;
}
.ui-menu ul li {
    display:block;
    float:none;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul {
    left:20px !important;
    width:100%;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul li {
    width:auto;
}
.ui-menu ul li ul li a {
    float:left;
}
.ui-menu > li {
    margin: 5px 5px !important;
    padding: 0 0 !important;
}
.ui-menu > li > a { 
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-icon { 
    margin-top: 0.3em !important;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu .ui-menu li { 
    float: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: What's your JQuery code?

Answer (score 2):

This should make the border blue

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #B7DDF2; 
}
```

Comment: I +1'd while there was no `.ui-menu` in that selector. Worth nothing that `.ui-widget-content {` on its own should change all jQuery UI widget borders.

Comment: @Popnoodles Okay then

Comment: @ManofSnow your answer didn't help before your edit.

Comment: @ManofSnow In your very first version you didn't tell where you added it and colour was wrong.

Comment: @ManofSnow This answer was fully formed and showed the correct colour that OP requires, not a single line that OP would have to decipher, then complain that it wasn't the same blue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by adding `border: 1px solid #B7DDF2` to the CSS of `nav` (or .ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all):

(CSS)

```
#nav
{
    border: 1px solid #B7DDF2
}
```

or

```
.ui-menu.ui-widget-content
{
    border: 1px solid #B7DDF2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your menu's border color is being called from the .ui-widget-content class on line 800 in jquery-ui.css. You can modify it from there.

Comment: Hi Mike. Welcome to SO. There was already an answer that does what you describe, so no real need to repost. It would be useful, however, if you are the first to spot the problem, to show the solution rather than describe it.